# Android Gradle 3.0 and "Unresolved reference R" for a local library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-3.0

I'm struggling to update my project to compile with Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1. Facts:

- `app` project depends on a local library: `lib`
- `./gradlew assembleDebug` for `app` fails at compiling `lib` with error `Unresolved reference: R`
- Building `lib` as a standalone project succeeds
- `package` in `AndroidManifest` of either projects is the same
- I tried to disable aapt2 (`android.enableAapt2=false` in `gradle.properties`) - no luck
- May be relevant: Using Kotlin (1.2.21)

What am I missing? Seems pretty straightforward, yet I couldn't find the reason why R is not generated while building the `app`, yet it is when building the `lib` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in **using symlink to library directory**. I modified `settings.gradle` to point out to the right dir instead:

```
project(':lib').projectDir = new File('/path/to/the/lib')
```

Comment: i still can't figure it out, what am i missing? android studio 3.1.1